# Interpolate or fit a curve over multiple geographical points

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have such a dataframe:

| id | x | y | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 51.0234 | 0.3467 | ... |
| 1 | 52.8762 | 0.2890 | ... |
| 2 | 54.0342 | 0.4510 | ... |
| 3 | 50.1237 | 0.1870 | ... |

and so on. This is how points look like on the plot.
[image: General view of the curve]
[image: Zoomed points]
The points are gps data and they form a curve. I want to interpolate or fit the curve over those points. The problem with fitting is that I do not know the exact curve function because points might differ in different timestamps.

I tried to use such an interpolation functions:

- **scipy.CubicSpline**
- **scipy.UnivariateSpline**
- **scipy.interp1d**

Most of them could not perform a proper interpolation over such points. It seems that the curve is to complex for that (or maybe I am wrong). Here is an example code:

```py
spline = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0.05)
x_smooth = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000)
y_smooth = spline(x_smooth)
```

I also tried other solution to connect such points (Travelling salesman problem) and then perform curve smoothing but the computation time was to high as the dataframe consists of 1_000_000 rows or even more. Another idea was to perform some poins clustering to cluster 10-50 points into one that is the mean of those points but the computational time was also high.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve such a problem?

Comment: Is the second picture just a close up detail of the first one?

Comment: Can you provide more (x, y) pairs, please?

Comment: Yes, the second picture is just the close up detail of the curve